# Is there any software that can exhibit 4th dimensional objects in a 4D space?

Tags: computer-science, computational-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis, simulation, dimensional-analysis

I want to model an object in 4D. Just like the 3D simulation softwares (like Autodesk Maya, 3D Studio Max, etc.) but in 4D.

Please keep in mind that I'm looking for a computer program that can simulate/display 4 spatial dimensions, and not 3 spatial + 1 temporal. For example, I want to model a hypercube.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have available a holographic projector to use as your screen...

Comment: [Globular](http://globular.science/) does this, but I am not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: That would be an interesting program, coincidentally there exist 4,5,6, and even 7D rubrics cubes online that you can play. This post made me remember that